# I tried several options but this error still occurs: org.testng.TestNGException: Check to make sure it can be instantiate

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testing, automated-tests, testng

**Problem:** I am a beginner with selenium and automation testing and I am writing a selenium script using java, TestNG, and maven. When I write everything in one class, all works fine, but I want to have a package for all objects, a package for tests, and Base Class with the main setting. The project will contain a class for every page from the website and a class for all tests.

What I tried:
**When I try to modify something appear another error is from the constructor in BaseClass and I have no idea why
The base class is this:**
I tried with

```java
public BaseClass(WebDriver driver) {           
    this.driver = driver; 
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}
```

or `PagegeFactory.initElements(new AjaxElementLocatorFactory(driver, TimeoutValue), this);` and didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic problem with your code is that you have parameterised your constructor.

TestNG ONLY knows how to invoke the default constructor (no arguments constructor). In your case, you have a parameterised constructor that seems to accept a `WebDriver driver` instance and TestNG does not know how to instantiate this.

The easiest fix to get past this problem would be to do the following:

1. Remove the parameterised constructor and just stick to default constructor.
2. Employ an approach which abstracts out the WebDriver logic which your tests can basically invoke to get a WebDriver instance.
3. Also please try to seggregate page object classes and test classes. (Your current class `AnalizesiPreturi` violates this expectation)

Sometime back I built a library called `autospawn` which uses an annotation driven approach for browser instance management.

You can refer to https://github.com/RationaleEmotions/autospawn#how-to-use-testng

Alternatively you can make use of TestNG listeners using which you can instantiate webdriver instance and make it available via a `ThreadLocal` instance.

For more details please refer to my blog post https://rationaleemotions.com/parallel_webdriver_executions_using_testng/

Comment: I do that and now I have the following error java: constructor BaseClass in class com.selenium.Base.BaseClass cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver       or                 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.create(Ljava/util/concurrent/ExecutorService;)Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/SimpleTimeLimiter;

Comment: I have no idea how to adapt to my code. I tried with parameter, without parameter, but....another errors